# Increment by more than one number with jQuery.animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have a script that animates from zero to its value. Is it possible to increment this number by more than one at a time?

e.g 1, 5, 10, 15...... 100

```js
jQuery({ countNum: 0 }).animate({ 
  countNum: jQuery('.ticker').text()
}, {
  duration: 2000,
  easing: 'swing',
  step: function() {  
    jQuery('.ticker').text((Math.floor(this.countNum)));
  },
  complete: function() {  
    jQuery('.ticker').text((Math.floor(this.countNum)));
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ticker">100</div>
```

Comment: _"by more than one at a time"_ - Remove the `Math.floor()` call and you will see that the number is not incremented by one

Comment: `this.countNum * 5` `this.countNum * 10` `this.countNum * 15`

Comment: You're also using `swing` easing, so *very* roughly you get something like 0,0.1,0.2,0.5,3,7,9.5,9.8,9.9,10.  If you want a fixed increment (1,2,3,4) then use `easing:'linear'` see https://api.jquery.com/animate/ Easing or a relatively simple `setInterval`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:
HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ticker">100</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery({ countNum: 0 }).animate(
  {
    countNum: jQuery(".ticker").text()/5
  },
  {
    duration: 4000,
    easing: "linear",
    step: function () {
      jQuery(".ticker").text(Math.floor(this.countNum)*5);
    },
    complete: function () {
      jQuery(".ticker").text(Math.floor(this.countNum)*5);
    }
  }
);
```